# Show user location on ios map using Delphi

Tags: ios, delphi, mobile, pascal, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I wanted to show Apple map on my Delphi multi-device application. I am using TMapView component to display my map. It manages to show the map on my application, but it cannot show the user's current location on the map with a marker on it. How can I solve this? The tutorial I am referencing is from [here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_a_Map_Component_to_Work_with_Maps_(iOS_and_Android)).

Comment: Look at the **See Also** section at the bottom of the tutorial you linked for a link to another tutorial titled  [Mobile Tutorial: Using Location Sensors (iOS and Android)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_a_Map_Component_to_Work_with_Maps_(iOS_and_Android)).

Comment: @Brian I looked into that link before, but nothing useful to solve my problem. Or if you any ides how to use MapKit in Delphi?

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is the option UserLocation in the TMapView.LayerOptions property as on the image below:

[image: Properties window screenshot]